# Sort array in ascending order [Java]

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

So recently I came across a problem when trying to sort in ascending order of an array:

```
private PlaneSeat[] sortSeats() {
    PlaneSeat[] tempAr = seat;
    int temp, tempI, tempJ;

    for (int i = 0; i < tempAr.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < tempAr.length; j++) {
            if (tempAr[i].isOccupied()) {
                tempI = tempAr[i].getCustomerID();
                tempJ = tempAr[j].getCustomerID();
                if (tempI < tempJ) {
                    temp = tempI;
                    tempI = tempJ;
                    tempJ = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return tempAr;
}
```

What I am trying to do is I am assigning seat array to a temporary array because I do not want to override the value in original array. Then, I am trying to compare the customerID in temporary array and sort according to the ascending order of customerID. Then, from my main method, I am calling it:

```
tempAr = sortSeats();
        for (int i = 0; i < tempAr.length; i++) {
            if (tempAr[i].isOccupied()) {
                System.out.println("SeatID " + tempAr[i].getSeatID()
                        + " assigned to CustomerID "
                        + tempAr[i].getCustomerID());
            }
        }
```

However, with these, it does not sort according to the customerID, it still returning me the original array. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In addition to the answer you got: `PlaneSeat[] tempAr = seat;` doesn't create a copy of the original array. It just defines another variable referring to the same array.

Comment: Oh, and of course, unless you're learning how to write your own sorting algorithm, you should just use Arrays.sort().

Answer (score 0):

here you just swap the temp variable but didn't set it to original array:

```
if (tempI < tempJ) {
                temp = tempI;
                tempI = tempJ;
                tempJ = temp;
 }
```

so I think you should swap the PlaneSeat in your array:

```
if (tempI < tempJ) {
               PlaneSeat tempSeat = tempAr[i];
               tempAr[i] = tempAr[j];
               tempAr[j] = tempSeat;
 }
```

Comment: Oh yeah that makes sense! But do you have any ideas how?

Answer (score 0):

temp, tempI etc. are primitive variables so they get reassigned but the original array doesn't change. What you need is to switch array data:

```
if (tempI < tempJ) {
   tempAr[i] = tempj;
   tempAr[j] = tempI;
}
```